# Possible to upload a file from client's machine to a server that is external to the webserver hosting the form?

Tags: php, jquery, file, cross-domain, uploading

To setup the scenario, there are three machines:  (1) The client's machine, (2) the webserver, (3) and a file storage server.  These three machines are not within the same local-area-network, nor are they within the same domain.  The webserver is running Apache with PHP, and the storage server is running IIS7 with PHP as well.

I have a webpage--hosted on the webserver--that contains a file-upload module.  When a user uploads a file from that webpage, I want the file to be stored directly onto the storage server, not the web server itself.  I want to avoid transferring the file from the webserver to the storage server via cURL or a system-level command like "scp" because that seems like a waste of network resources and the user's time.

Is this possible to do securely, and what are the recommended implementations for doing so?

I did find [a nice, multi-file uploader on GitHub by blueimp](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) that can do [cross-domain uploads](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Cross-domain-uploads), but after following the directions for setting up cross-domain uploads, I get an error from my browser's debug console that reads:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://storageserver.com/scripts/process_uploads.php`. Origin `http://webserver.com` is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

While I realize it is not the most secure code, I added the following to the process_uploads.php script for troubleshooting purposes:

> header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

For clarification purposes, here is the way I wrote the form element that is parsed by the jQuery-File-Upload plugin:

```
<form id="fileupload" action="http://storageserver.com:8080/scripts/process_uploads.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Has anybody has success implementing cross-domain file uploading?  If so, can you shed some light as to what might be a robust solution.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you acquire a time machine and can go back a few years to when the web was a more trusting place, and browsers didn't protect against this sort of thing.  Cross-domain rules seem to change every few months anyway.  You'd be wise to avoid that can of worms if you can.

I see two options, neither of them great.  There are undoubtedly more.

**First: Submit forms to your file server, and have it submit forms to your web server.**

This depends (heavily of course) on reliable connectivity between the two servers.  You said you didn't want to copy files from the web server to the filer.  So move your data the other way instead.  A few bytes of form will be less of a hit than copying files in the other direction.  So submit the whole form to your file server, and have a PHP form handler there submit the non-file portions (including the source IP and a session identifier) to the web server.  You don't even need to store form data on the filer, just have it relay the web server's results back to the browser.  Don't forget to consider authentication and security when you design this.

**Second: Use JavaScript or Flash to upload two forms**

Place your non-file form content in one form, and the file in a separate form.  Catch the Submit of one form and have it submit the other form (to the other server) as well.  This is a BAD solution because it relies on JavaScript on the browser, which isn't always there.  (You can break your site by requiring it, but I don't recommend it.)  Since you're already using jQuery, you can probably figure out a solution on your own.

I don't know how you'd do this in Flash, but I'm sure it's possible.  And I'm equally sure you shouldn't do it in Flash.  Fie on all closed source "web" technologies.  Always use open tools.

That's all I've got.  But I'm a sysadmin.  I'll be interested to see what other folks come up with.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  I would never use Flash to upload files. . . that seems so archaic :)  However, I went with using blueimp's jQuery file uploader from GitHub, and placed that on the fileserver.  Then, on the webserver, I created a page that makes use of the easyXDM plugin which loads the remote file server's uploader widget within an iframe and allows for communication b/w the two pages.  So far, works like a charm